# Replace input type=file by an image

Tags: css, image, file, button, input

Like a lot of people, I'd like to customize the ugly `input type=file`, and I know that it can't be done without some hacks and/or `javascript`. But, the thing is that in my case the upload file buttons are just for uploading images (**jpeg|jpg|png|gif**), so I was wondering if I could use a "`clickable`" image which would act exactly as an input type file (show the dialog box, and same $_FILE on submitted page).
I found some workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351685/html-css-using-a-image-for-input-typefile), and [this interesting one](http://www.shauninman.com/assets/examples/styling-file-inputs/) too (but does not work on Chrome =/).

What do you guys do when you want to add some style to your file buttons? If you have any point of view about it, just hit the answer button ;)

Comment: For everyone landing here, http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/ might also be worth a look. (Not affiliated with that site in any way, shape or form.)

Comment: You can check [**How to make photo to work as input type file?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334430/3669624).

Answer (score 371):

This works really well for me:

```css
.image-upload>input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-lollipop/128/Downloads-icon.png"/>
  </label>

  <input id="file-input" type="file" />
</div>
```

Basically the **for** attribute of the label makes it so that **clicking the label is the same as clicking the specified input**.

Also, the display property set to none makes it so that the file input isn't rendered at all, hiding it nice and clean.

Tested in Chrome but according to the web should work on all major browsers. :)

**EDIT:**
Added JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c5s42vdz/

Comment: i'm not sure if people still consider it a 'major browser', but this doesn't seem to work in IE7

Comment: @Chet it seems to be working on the latest versions of Safari (7+)
Which version are you using?

Comment: @Toto For me it's working in IE11, I've added a JSFiddle so you can check it as well.

Comment: @hardsetting You are right! Sorry (Maybe I was in a different document mode, ie8 or lower)

Comment: sorry but I think this code must be updated with the filename or at least a message that the file has been selected successfully. The user has no visual input on what happened after he selected the file. Could this be done please? Perhaps change to a different image, when a file is chosen?

Comment: I'm curious, how accessible is this?

Comment: @hard I Want To Thank you for an elegant simple example. And you explained what makes it work. And I was just wrecking my mind about how I was going to stuff and Image as a placeholder for a input of type file. And I am a consistent user of label tag with all inputs.

Comment: Dope answer and explanation. Very simple and concise

Answer (score 69):

Actually it can be done in pure css and it's pretty easy...

HTML Code

```
<label class="filebutton">
Browse For File!
<span><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"></span>
</label>
```

CSS Styles

```
label.filebutton {
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

label span input {
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -700px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    cursor: pointer;
    _cursor: hand;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

The idea is to position the input absolutely inside your label. set the font size of the input to something large, which will increase the size of the "browse" button. It then takes some trial and error using the negative left / top properties to position the input browse button behind your label.

When positioning the button, set the alpha to 1. When you've finished set it back to 0 (so you can see what you're doing!)

Make sure you test across browsers because they'll all render the input button a slightly different size.

Comment: Thanks Toby, why is there 'left: -700px;' ? In firefox the file input field is actually floating by the left side of a page...it doesn't stick to the label span ... If I remove 'left: -700px;' it works fine

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Sloin left:-700px because he wanted to get the browse button to be over the button so the cursor will be a pointer and not the text cursor.

Answer (score 22):

Great solution by @hardsetting,
But I made some improvements to make it work with Safari(5.1.7) in windows

```css
.image-upload > input {
  visibility:hidden;
  width:0;
  height:0
}
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
  <label for="file-input">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=UPLOAD" style="pointer-events: none"/>
  </label>

  <input id="file-input" type="file" />
</div>
```

I have used `visibility: hidden, width:0` instead of `display: none` for safari issue and added `pointer-events: none` in `img` tag to make it working if input file type tag is in FORM tag.

Seems working for me in all major browsers.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: there is no need to add style="pointer-events: none" its create the issue to open the browse file.

Answer (score 19):

A much better way than writing JS is to use native,
and it turns to be lighter than what was suggested:

```
<label>
  <img src="my-image.png">
  <input type="file" name="myfile" style="display:none">
</label>
```

This way the `label` is automatically connected to the input that is hidden.
Clicking on the label is like clicking on the field.

Comment: Simplest answer and still best one

Answer (score 7):

You can replace image automatically with newly selected image.

```
<div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
        <img id="previewImg" src="https://icon-library.net/images/upload-photo-icon/upload-photo-icon-21.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="previewFile(this);" style="display: none;" />
    </div>




<script>
        function previewFile(input){
            var file = $("input[type=file]").get(0).files[0];

            if(file){
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function(){
                  $("#previewImg").attr("src", reader.result);
              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Probably the most complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/). They need Flash but do everything you want without troubles.

Any `<input type="file">` based workaround that tries to trigger the "open file" dialog by means other than clicking on the actual control could be removed from browsers for security reasons at any time. (I *think* in the current versions of FF and IE, it is not possible any more to trigger that event programmatically.)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen them around too, but I think that both of them need a flash player to work, and I do not want to add another mandatory layer to users. Plus are you sure that they will send the exact same type of data as the input file ones do? I do not want to retest all my PHP done in the submit page. Cheers.

Comment: @niko no, they work differently, they are not form elements but send the file to a receiving script on their own, so you would probably have to change your script's workflow. If that's not an option, I think you can't do better than Shaun Inman did in the post you link to...

Comment: I'm afraid so then, that's really a shame. Isn't there anything about it in future CSS implementation? Thanks for the replies anyway :)

Comment: @niko you're welcome. Good question about the CSS - I don't know actually, but HTML 5 may well bring new things here. Check out http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload for example.

Comment: Yeah it seems promising even if the demo http://www.appelsiini.net/demo/html5_upload/demo.html does not display with my FF 3.6.3 whereas it says I do need FF 3.6.x Anyway, to go back to my issue, currently HTML/CSS/Javscript (but no flash) only allow me to do what? Some fonts and "color" customization? Am I right then? Cheers.

Comment: @niko here's a good overview on workarounds: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html with the limitation that they don't work on Chrome - I don't know what the state of things is there.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that page, which could be the better solution in my case, but the issue with erasing the image chosen plus some limitations on old browsers make me a little reluctant. Btw I don't see any trouble on Chrome 4.1 :)

Answer (score 6):

This is my method if i got your point

**## HTML**

```
<label for="FileInput">
    <img src="tools/img/upload2.png" style="cursor:pointer" onmouseover="this.src='tools/img/upload.png'" onmouseout="this.src='tools/img/upload2.png'" alt="Injaz Msila" style="float:right;margin:7px" />
</label>
<form action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" id="FileInput" style="cursor: pointer;  display: none"/>
    <input type="submit" id="Up" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

**## jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#FileInput" ).change(function() {
      $( "#Up" ).click();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have had lots of issues with hidden and not visible inputs over the past decade sometimes things are way simpler than we think.

I have had a little wish with IE 5,6,7,8 and 9 for not supporting the opacity and thus the file input would cover the upload image however the following css code has resolved the issue.

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

The following snipped is tested on chrome, IE 5,6,7,8,9,10 the only issue in IE 5 is that it does not support auto margin.

Run the snippet simply copy and paste the CSS and HTML modify the size as you like.

```css
.file-upload{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 margin:40px auto;
 border:1px solid #f0c0d0;
 border-radius:100px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
.file-upload input{
 position:absolute;
 height:400px;
 width:400px;
 left:-200px;
 top:-200px;
 background:transparent;
 opacity:0;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);  
}
.file-upload img{
 height:70px;
 width:70px;
 margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-upload">
<!--place upload image/icon first !-->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy62M.png" />
<!--place input file last !-->
<input type="file" name="somename" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

its really simple you can try this:

```
$("#image id").click(function(){
    $("#input id").click();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put an image instead, and do it like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/uploadButton.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />
<input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
});
```

**CAVEAT**:
In IE9 and IE10 if you trigger the onclick in a file input via javascript the form gets flagged as 'dangerous' and cannot be submmited with javascript, no sure if it can be submitted traditionaly.

Answer (score 2):

The input itself is hidden with CSS visibility:hidden.

Then you can have whatever element you whish - anchor or image.., when the anchor/image is clicked, trigger a click on the hidden input field - the dialog box for selecting a file will appear.

EDIT: Actually it works in Chrome and Safari, I just noticed that is not the case in FF4Beta

Answer (score 2):

**Working Code:**

just hide input part and do like this.

```
<div class="ImageUpload">
   <label for="FileInput">
      <img src="../../img/Upload_Panel.png" style="width: 18px; margin-top: -316px; margin-left: 900px;"/>
   </label>

  <input id="FileInput" type="file" onchange="readURL(this,'Picture')" style="cursor: pointer;  display: none"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
        form input[type="file"] {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple File Upload</title>
  <meta name="" content="">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <label for="fileToUpload">
      <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/mjzvuzi5b/uploader_image.png" />
    </label>
    <input type="File" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**RUN SNIPPET or Just copy the above code and execute. You will get what you wanted. Very simple and effective without javascript. Enjoy!!!**

Comment: Sadly theese methods not working in Safari for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function upl() {
    var fileSelector = document.createElement('input');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('name', 'uploimg');
    fileSelector.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    fileSelector.click();
    fileSelector.style.display = "none";

    fileSelector.onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = "Uploaded";
    };

    document.getElementById("par_form").appendChild(fileSelector);

}
</script>

<form id="par_form">
    <img src="image_url" onclick="upl()"><br>
    <span id="indicator"></span><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).