# Open image dialog box when click on icon

Tags: javascript

```html
<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change your avatar">
<img class="rounded" id="avatar" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3456749?s=160" alt="avatar">
       <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
     </label>
```

select image dialog box opens when image clicked how to make this to an icon. popup when a click icon!

```html
<label class="btn-aux" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change your avatar" for="profile_image" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="ion ion-edit"></i>
         <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*"></label>
```

here nothing happens.....! how to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855589/replace-input-type-file-by-an-image

Comment: <label class="btn-aux" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change your avatar" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <i id="avatar" class="ion ion-edit"></i>
      <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
    </label> its done

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```css
.ion {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) 0 0 no-repeat
}
#input {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change your avatar">
  <i class="ion"></i>
  <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*">
</label>
```