# How to put <Input> tag inside <img> tag

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I just want to know how I can put the  tag inside an  so that when I click on the image the  tag is activated. I'm using angular 4 and bootstrap 4. this is my code:

```
<input type="file" class="css-1u2oed9 eehmg7h4" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
                <img 
                data-src="holder.js/200x200" 
                class="rounded mx-auto d-block" 
                src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_164e3f66702%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_164e3f66702%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2274.4296875%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" 
                data-holder-rendered="true" 
                style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:5px;">
```

TypeScript Method Component:

```
onFileChange(event) {
      this.loading=true;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        this.photo = event.target.files[0];
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.photo);
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          this.image=event.target.result;
          console.log(this.image);
        }
      }
    }
```

I remind you that what I want is to click on the image and that I can select another one in the file system to change it.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: How do I put an img tag inside of an input tag?

A: You *DON'T*.  That's not legal HTML!

You MAY, however, put both in a `<div>` tag such that the image is visually associated with your input tag.

For example:

[Replace input type=file by an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855589/replace-input-type-file-by-an-image)

HTML:

```
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
        <img src="placeholder.jpg"/>
    </label>

    <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Adding an alt text  to the img tag or text inside the label tag would make it accessible.