# How to make image to behave like file input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, click

When the default photo is clicked it should make a user to select a file from his computer other than making an `input type = "file"` that makes the user to first click on browse button than select a file. A user should directly click on default photo and a file selection window should appear.

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Profile Click
        </title>
        <style>
            #file{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function pro1(){
                document.prolis.getElementById("image") = document.prolis.getElementById("file");
            }
        </script>
        <form name = "prolis">
        <img src = "index.jpg" id = "image" onclick = "pro1()";>
        <input type = "file" id = "file">
    </body>
</html>
Mozilla Firefox console shows "TypeError: document.prolis.getElementById is not a function".
```

How should I make this function work?
This is my default image:

[image]

Comment: `window.prolis`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the `image` behave like an input `file` element, you can just call the `input` file `.click()` method when you click on the `img`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function pro1(){
   document.getElementById("file").click();
}
```

**Demo:**

```html
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Profile Click
        </title>
        <style>
            #file{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function pro1(){
                document.getElementById("file").click();
            }
        </script>
        <form name = "prolis">
        <img src = "index.jpg" id = "image" onclick = "pro1()";>
        <input type = "file" id = "file">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:**

You just need to use `document.getElementById("file")` to access an element by its `id`.

Comment: And you can assign it back to the image once you fetch the file

Comment: @karthik Yes of course that's another thing. But I don't think, that's what he si looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select element by id you should do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('element_id')
```

If you want to select form element you should do it like this:

```
document.form_name.element_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a click event for #file in your function

```
function pro1(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('file')[0].click();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace image automatically with newly selected image.

```
<div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
        <img id="previewImg" src="https://icon-library.net/images/upload-photo-icon/upload-photo-icon-21.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="previewFile(this);" style="display: none;" />
    </div>

<script>
        function previewFile(input){
            var file = $("input[type=file]").get(0).files[0];

            if(file){
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function(){
                  $("#previewImg").attr("src", reader.result);
              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    </script>
```